# Windows 10 Photos app displays error "The app didn't start."

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1703

I just updated my Windows 10 today (to v1703) and one problem I had was that whenever I tried to open an image file associated with the default Photos app it would display an error message saying "The app didn't start" right away. (No crashing, no hanging). I can't even launch the app from the start menu. Is there any way to fix this or do I have to use the old Windows Photo Viewer?

[image]

Comment: If you manually launch the photo application without a file loaded what happens?

Comment: @Ramhound It closes itself immediately

Comment: look if you have done "tweaks" around UAC settings.

Comment: @magicandre1981 today (the day after I've posted this question) the photos app is working smoothly. Must be a bug

Comment: We are certainly glad to see that you found a solution, but please don't put "Solved" in the title of your question. Within our community, the fact that you designated an answer as the official solution already shows us that the problem has been solved. Thanks for your help!

Comment: How did you solve it?